# "idle timeout reached for" and "No alive nodes. All the 1 nodes seem to be down"

Tags: php, elasticsearch

We have elasticsearch 8.7 cluster, one master and three nodes are data.

php config

```
stream timeout => 10 mins
```

official client instantiation https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php

```
ClientBuilder::create()
   ->setHttpClientOptions([
      'no_proxy' => true,
      'proxy' => '',
   ])       
   ->setHosts(["http://elastichost:9200"])->build();
```

Here is problem

If we put 20 shards per node, script runs well, and succeeds after multiple hours. We have up to date indexes and everything is good

But if we put few shards (1, 2, 5) per node, script fails after 10 mins. Debugging code showed that we exceed timeout of 10 mins according to stream_timeout and have error message such "no alive nodes exists".

Investigating code

[image]

tried to put ping when script decides that host is dead, but without success

```
->setNodePool(
          new SimpleNodePool(
             new RoundRobin(),
             new ElasticsearchResurrect()
          )
       )
```

It keeps dead connection and tries to perform request. Moreover we have to pass some big value  of no. of retries, otherwise no.of tries exceeds (

[image]

So, my main question is:

How to bypass this issue? and
How can no.shards affect this?

p.s: increasing timeout is simple enough, need to understand and find more elegant way

Comment: Also tried to set Keep-Alive to false (CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE), but library does not support this option

Answer (score 0):

The only solution was to increase timeout